# Aromaticity of conjugated cyclic ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Consider the following compounds:

1. Cyclopenta-2,4-dien-1-one
2. Cyclopent-2-en-1-one

In both compounds, I can visualize a resonating structure in which the ring follows Huckel's rules by:

1. The $\ce{C=O}$ $\pi$-electrons transfer to $\ce{C}$.
2. The $\ce{C=O}$ $\pi$-electrons transfer to $\ce{O}$.

A test that I gave, gave 2 as aromatic but not 1, why?

Also can you recommend a lucid source with an explanation of aromaticity that has lots of examples?

Comment: You know Huckel's rules? There's no reason to think any of the two would be aromatic.

Comment: Possibly the second compound is misprinted.  Cycle**prop**-2-en-1-one would have an aromatic contribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cyclopent-2,4-dien-1-one is not aromatic as you suggested by the resonance structure (see **A** on the following diagram). That resonance is forbidden and does not exist, ever (I marked it with a red cross). Also, Note that the conjugated $\mathrm{sp^2}$ carbons of the original structure are not cyclic. Nonetheless, its allowed resonance is given in **B**, and therefore, cyclopent-2,4-dien-1-one is considered to be *antiaromatic* (Ref.1) due to a significant polar resonance structure (the carbocation is formed at the carbonyl carbon; see **B** on the diagram):

[image: Cyclopenta-2,4-dien-1-one]

It is a very unstable compound and reacts with itself in a Diels-Alder reaction to give a more stable dimer, resemble cyclopentadiene. It is noteworthy that all attempts to synthesize cyclopenta-2,4-dien-1-one have been failed and, yielded only a dimerization product (see **C** on the diagram).

Cyclopent-2-en-1-one is, on the other hand, not aromatic or antiaromatic, but a $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated cyclic ketone, which is also very stable.

**Note:** You may read https://nptel.ac.in/courses/104103071/module7/lec17/2.html, https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Arenes/Properties_of_Arenes/Aromaticity, and https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2017/02/23/rules-for-aromaticity/ to learn about aromaticity.

**References:**

1. R. Pal, S. Mukherjee, S. Chandrasekhar, T. N. Guru Row, “Exploring Cyclopentadienone Antiaromaticity: Charge Density Studies of Various Tetracyclones,” *J. Phys. Chem. A* **2014**, *118(19)*, 3479–3489 (https://doi.org/10.1021/jp5010924).

Comment: But this article says it's partly anti aromatic https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo034401j

Comment: I mentioned that in my answern(Ref.1). The question is not about antiaromaticity, any way.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood the answer. I the paper where they referred to dimer as something else than the diel's alder reaction.

Comment: _its allowed resonance is given in B, and therefore, cyclopent-2,4-dien-1-one is considered to be antiaromatic_ but wouldn't B resonance structure be extremely unstable and therefore contribute very less to hybrid and therefore hybrid will be more close to A which will be _non-aroamtic_?